# Typescript Generic Wrapper Type

Tags: typescript

I have multiple queries that return a similar type and I want to define a generic wrapper to include all the queries.

Base Queries :

```
type QueryA = {
 __typename?: 'Query';
 productsConnection: {
  __typename?: 'ProductConnection';
  edges: Array<{
   __typename?: 'ProductEdge';
   cursor: string;
   node: Product
  }>;
  pageInfo: PageInfo;
  aggregate: Aggregate;
 }
}
```

```
type QueryB = {
 __typename?: 'Query';
 productVariantConnection: {
  __typename?: 'productVariantConnection';
  edges: Array<{
   __typename?: 'productVariantEdge';
   cursor: string;
   node: ProductVariant
  }>;
  pageInfo: PageInfo;
  aggregate: Aggregate;
 }
}
```

I've tried to handle it that way :

```
type Edge<T> = {
  cursor: string;
  node: T;
}

type CursorQuery<T> = {
  [key: string]: {
    edges: Array<Edge<T>>,
    pageInfo: PageInfo,
    aggregate: Aggregate
  }
};
```

I make a test call like that

```
const test = (await sdk.GetProductCursor()) as CursorQuery<Product>
```

But I end up having these errors :

> Type 'QueryA' is not compatible with type 'CursorQuery'.

> Property '__typename' is incompatible with index signature.

> Type 'string' is incompatible with type '{ edges: Edge[]; pageInfo: PageInfo; aggregate: Aggregate; }'

What I do not understand is that __typename property is not mandatory, and should not block the type convertion. Even if I extend my types like that it does the same error :

```
type Edge<T> = {
  cursor: string;
  node: T;
}

type CursorHeader = {
  __typename?: 'Query';
}

type CursorQuery<T> = CursorHeader & {
  [key: string]: {
    edges: Array<Edge<T>>,
    pageInfo: PageInfo,
    aggregate: Aggregate
  }
};
```

Comment: The index signature in `CursorQuery` is conflcting with the `__typename` property. An string index signature enforces that every string key (which `__typename` is one of) must have the type defined by the index signature. We could modify `CursorQuery` to also take the property name as demonstrated [here](https://tsplay.dev/NrX0oW) which would remove the index signature. Would this answer your question?

Comment: Thanks it helped a lot, i'm now a step further. There is nevertheless still some problems in my implementation. I will edit my post to reflect your solution and the remaining problems tomorrow.